# Can two iPhone 5c phones be paired with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to pair two iPhone 5c phones with Bluetooth? Both phones have OS 8.1.2, both are shown as having the same name; they are in the same Verizon plan. I’ve gone to Bluetooth, activated it, and both phones are shown as discoverable. Neither will show the other device.
Can they be paired? If so, how do I accomplish that?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Is there something else you are trying to do? Transfer files, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. While Bluetooth technology is capable of sending files between smartphones, computers and other devices, Apple has limited the function of Bluetooth on its iOS devices. You cannot send files, contacts or playlists between iPhones or computers with the default software. Third-party apps may let you transfer files with Bluetooth; however, these generally work between iPhones and iOS devices only rather than phones and computers.